# how to implement elastic search using Java?

Tags: java

I want to implement elastic search using Java in windows environment.please provide me some implementation details.

Comment: [ElasticSearch lists several client and backend projects](http://www.elasticsearch.com/products/). Implementation details can be found in their codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To know more about the elastic search based on the Lucene
See the following link

[Elastic Search Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below link to understand the java api for the elastic search
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/
The rest api can be called and used accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project on gitHub https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest